# issue in myfirstmodule.js while try to include

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on node js on learning stage i am getting error.
Here is my code:

[[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4LDZ.png
[image])
myfirstmodule file is available in same folder but because of it i am getting error.
I have attached screenshots of command line and editor, please have a look at it.
Please help me.

Comment: Please include the code as text not a screenshot of the code.

Comment: var http = require('http');
var dt = require('./myfirstmodule');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.write("The date and time are currently: " + dt.myDateTime());
  res.end();
}).listen(8080);

Comment: `EADDRINUSE: address already in use` means something is already listening on port 8080. Try another port.

Comment: You also need to show us the contents of `myfirstmodule`.

Comment: myfirstmodule code:

exports.myDateTime = function () {
  return Date();
};